# Why radio not selected in ns-popover popup. Radio is only seleced in table last column popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nspopover

I am setting radio model in angular controller but it is set in only table's last column popup.

ns-popover is appear on table column click.

**Angular Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['nsPopover']);

app.controller('MainController', function ($q, $timeout) {
this.foo = "foobar!";

this.fields = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A'},
  {id: 2, name: 'B'},
  {id: 3, name: 'C'}
];

this.columns = [
    {
    id: 1,
    entries: [
        {columnType: 'a'},
      {columnType: 'b'},
      {columnType: 'c'}
    ]   
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    entries: [
        {columnType: 'a'},
      {columnType: 'b'},
      {columnType: 'c'}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    entries: [
        {columnType: 'a'},
      {columnType: 'b'},
      {columnType: 'c'}
    ]
  }
];

    $('#example').popover();
});
```

example is here
[jsfiddle popup example](http://jsfiddle.net/9dr33he9/63/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing to set current active index [updated fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9dr33he9/66/)

```
$scope.setIndex = function(index) {

    this.currentIndex = index;
};
this.currentIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Ravinder is absolutely right. We need to track  current index of ns-popover template.